# Add vector support for CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

https://vector.dev/docs/

I hope cnosdb can be used as the sink of vector, but I find that vector does not support sink. Is there any other way to make cnosdb the sink of vector

If it is really impossible to support vector sink in the short term, can you try to use vector as the sink type and then write cnosdb.